# Library for parsing XHTML files with XLINQ

Tags: .net, xml, linq, xhtml, linq-to-xml

When I realized I needed to create an index for approximately 50 XHTML pages, which may be added/deleted/renamed/moved in the future, I thought "No problem -- I'll write a quick index generator using LINQ to XML, since XHTML definitely counts as XML".

Of course, as soon as I tried running it, I found out about the fact that XLINQ chokes on XHTML entities like &nbsp;.  I got around it by using the following algorithm:

1. Read XHTML file into string.
2. Use regex search and replace on that string to add a section into the DOCTYPE that defines all relevant entities (because I only care about the "title" attribute in the files I read and my output file does not use any entities right now, it just sets them all to blank, but I may add the actual values later).
3. Parses the result into an XDocument.

To save a file, I do the opposite:

1. Save XDocument to a string.
2. Strip out the entity definitions.
3. Save to file.

My question is, are there any libraries (especially built-in .Net ones) I can use that will read XHTML files into XDocuments? The code I wrote has accomplished its purpose (to generate the current index and to test the rest of the generator program), and I would really prefer not to spend time testing it if someone else already wrote and tested the same thing.

Thank y'all so much for your time,

Ria.

**Edit:** Thank you so much; this works! I still have to do a little string processing when I save the XHTML (guess the library was not really made for that:)) and I had to fiddle with the source of the Agility Pack slightly to get it to stop indiscriminately sticking a CDATA section around the insides of every style attribute (even when there was already one present), but that's the point of Open Source, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be helpful: [LINQ & Lambda, Part 3: Html Agility Pack to LINQ to XML Converter](http://vijay.screamingpens.com/archive/2008/05/26/linq-amp-lambda-part-3-html-agility-pack-to-linq.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, this link appears to be broken now.

Comment: Look here: LINQ & Lambda, Part 3: Html Agility Pack to LINQ to XML Converter http://bit.ly/cYyZgu , long live to web.archive.org

Comment: In short, the article recommends you to use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and shows how to convert it into a `XDocument`.